# MySQL recursive query cte

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

The following query

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
  SELECT id, CAST(name AS CHAR(200)) AS name, parentid, icon, url, position,
         CAST(id AS CHAR(200)) AS path,
         0 as depth
  FROM categories WHERE parentid = 46
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id,
         c.name,
         c.parentid,
         c.icon,
         c.url,
         c.position,
         CONCAT(cte.path,',', c.id),
         cte.depth+1
  FROM categories c JOIN cte ON
  cte.id=c.parentid
)
SELECT id, path FROM cte ORDER BY id;
```

This returns two columns: `ID` and `Path`. If the ID is e.g. "52", the path is "50,51,52" where 50 and 51 are parents and grand parents and 52 is the ID itself. How can I get a result of "50,51" without the "52" id? Thanks !

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID </th>
<th>Parentid</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>    46  </td><td>   0   </td></tr>
<tr><td>    47  </td><td>   46  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    48  </td><td>   46  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    49  </td><td>   46  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    50  </td><td>   46  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    51  </td><td>   50  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    52  </td><td>   51  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    53  </td><td>   47  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    54  </td><td>   47  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    55  </td><td>   47  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    56  </td><td>   48  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    57  </td><td>   51  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    58  </td><td>   49  </td></tr>
<tr><td>    60  </td><td>   50  </td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide sample data

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, sorry but i am new to this, what is best way? dump of table and content .sql?

Comment: few rows will do, mainly on IDs 50, 51, 52

Comment: Thank you Akina, but it still gives a result "50,51,52" so the id is still included when I use your code

Comment: Provide sample data as INSERT INTO script.

Comment: O! your recursion is backward... if so then simply `SELECT id, TRIM(TRAILING CONCAT(',', id) FROM path) AS path FROM cte ORDER BY id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are tring to exclude those ID's which are not parent during the building of your `path` field values.

You can have conditional `select` using `WHEN` clause

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
  SELECT id, CAST(name AS CHAR(200)) AS name, parentid, icon, url, position,
         CAST(id AS CHAR(200)) AS path,
         0 as depth
  FROM categories WHERE parentid = 46
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id,
         c.name,
         c.parentid,
         c.icon,
         c.url,
         c.position,
         CASE WHEN  c.id not in (select parentid from categories) THEN CONCAT(cte.path)
              ELSE  CONCAT(cte.path,',', c.id) END as path
         ,cte.depth+1
  FROM categories c 
  JOIN cte ON cte.id=c.parentid
)
SELECT id, path FROM cte ORDER BY id;
```

Try this [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=v6cxFK2w22)